# Introducir un elemento en una posición determinada de un array

Tags: array, c, punteros

Estoy realizando un programa que lee un un número y una posición y debe introducir ese número en la posición correspondiente de myarray (tamaño 10). El problema es que en el código que tengo me sale un error en la linea myarray[y] = x;
El error me indica que debo usar un puntero. Hay alguna manera de realizar esta acción sin usar punteros? Gracias

```
void introducir(int myarray){
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    printf("Introduce el número que deseas meter en el array: \n");
    scanf("%i", &x);
    printf("Introduce la posición donde quieres colocar ese número: \n");
    scanf("%i", &y);
    if (y <= 9) {
        myarray[y] = x;
    }
    else printf("La posición indicada supera el número de elementos del array.\n");
}
```

Comment: `myarray` en tu función es un entero, no es un array. Cambia la declaración a `int marray[]`. No obstante, el programa que invoque a esa función debe asegurarse de que el array que le pasa tiene tamaño suficiente (10 elementos). Si tuviera menos, el intento de acceder a `myarray[y]` podría dar un error. La sintaxis `int myarray[]` por cierto es equivalente a `int *myarray`, por lo que en realidad estás usando punteros, pero con otra sintaxis que hace que se vean como arrays.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, toda la razón, me faltaba el [] despues de myarray. ya funciona perfecto! Y muy interesante eso que comentas al final, no tenía ni idea, soy nuevo en esto de la programación. Muchas gracias de nuevo!